# Web form security - POST token vs cookie token?

Tags: php, forms, security, session, cookies

So I'm implementing a token security system into my form, if SESSION and client-side token matches then form submission is considered valid.

Now I tried to implement client-size token inside form as hidden field since that is how tutorials do it. Now I have a little bit of technical reason why using cookies instead of form hidden field would be better option for me. However I'm not sure if that's acceptable thing to do.

Functionality-wise does it change anything that I use cookie as client-side token instead of form hidden field? Is there any security concern there?

Comment: Although it's rare, users might have disabled cookies on their browser.